# Sending custom non-standard HTTP status code with PHP

Tags: php, apache, http

I cannot find the right way to send a custom HTTP status code with PHP (for example: 454).
I've tried using:

```
header('HTTP/1.1 454', true);
header('X-PHP-Response-Code: 454', true);
```

with no avail. Even if I get the `X-PHP-Response-Code: 454` line in the response header, a `HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error` is always added at the top of it, overriding the status code.

I've tried `http_response_code()` too.

Is there any way to send a custom non-standard HTTP status code with PHP?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to add the HTTP status description to the header. For example:

```
    header('HTTP/1.1 454 My Custom Status', true);
```

PHP discards non-standard HTTP codes when provided without their description.

Comment: A description is not required; according to spec it can be empty. But the space after the status code _is_ required.